# Via psexec, how to output cmd result to file on remote machine? eg echo hello >file

Tags: cmd, psexec

The following command writes 'hello' into a txt file:

```
echo hello >c:\output.txt
```

How can this be adapted to work as a remote command when using psexec? The following doesn't behave in the same way:

```
PsExec.exe -nobanner -accepteula \\IP -u username -p password -n 30 -h -i 1 cmd /c echo hello >c:\output.txt
```

c:\output.txt is not created on the remote machine

Answer (score 1):

PsExec.exe -nobanner -accepteula \IP -u username -p password -n 30 -h -i 1 cmd /c "echo hello>c:\output.txt"